# Как сделать проверку сообщения на совпадение в файле Вк бот (vkbottle)?

Tags: python, вконтакте, бот

Пишу вк бота используя vkbottle, хочу сделать проверку приходящего сообщения на соответствие в файле hello.txt
Файл имеет построчное содержимое: 
Привет
Здрасти
Здравствуйте
и т.д
Например если пользователь написал "Здрасти", бот проверил этот файл и если есть совпадение ответил ему "И тебе привет"
В данный момент бот отвечает так:

```
@bot.on.message(text=["Привет", "Здравствуйте"])
async def message_handler(message: Message):
user = await bot.api.users.get(message.from_id)
await message.answer(f"И тебе привет, {user[0].first_name}")
```

Благодарю заранее за помощь, если кто поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то вам нужно расширить список допустимых сообщений от пользователей, чтобы не ограничиваться "Привет и здравствуйте", тогда вам стоит сначала прочитать значения из текстового файла, а затем подставить их вместо "Привет и здравствуйте", что-нибудь подобное:

```py
hello_messages = [] # пустой список допустимых значений
    
with open('file.txt', encoding="utf-8" ) as f: # открываем файл
    hello_messages = f.read().split("\n") # записываем в список значения из текстового файла
    
@bot.on.message(text=hello_messages) # Подставляем найденные значения
async def message_handler(message: Message):
    user = await bot.api.users.get(message.from_id)
    await message.answer(f"И тебе привет, {user[0].first_name}")
```

Дополнительно, я бы предложил посмотреть в сторону интеграции с базой данных, чтобы не оперировать текстовыми, например с PostgreSQL, в таблицах которой бы хранились шаблоны возможных сообщений от пользователей и ответы на них, а также иная важная для вашего проекта информация.

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ sigalgleb, в качестве параметра можно передавать анонимную функцию. В Python это lambda. Поищи да поймёшь о чем я.

И получится и тебя что-то такое:
@bot.on.message(text=lambda x: hello_messages)